# JSpinner focus issue

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel, jspinner

I'm on a Mac OS X using the default Look&Feel.  I have created a JSpinner and set some attributes on its associated TextField (alignment, color, non-editable).  The spinner works properly; it has the focus, but it doesn't *show* that it has the focus.  That is, the blue aqua L&F outline indicating focus is not present.  If I remove the indicated section of code, the spinner appears correctly showing it has the focus, but then the attributes I need aren't available.

I've run this program with the Nimbus L&F and everything shows correctly - the attributes AND the focus are present.  But I need the Apple default aqua L&F.  If this is a L&F issue rather than something I'm doing wrong, is there any other way to get the focus to *show* properly?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SpinnerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(spinner);

        // Comment out this section to see focus set properly
            JComponent editor = spinner.getEditor();            
            JSpinner.DefaultEditor spinnerEditor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor)editor;
            spinnerEditor.getTextField().setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);           
            spinnerEditor.getTextField().setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            spinnerEditor.getTextField().setEditable(false);
            spinnerEditor.getTextField().requestFocusInWindow();
        // End of this section

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Comment: `spinnerEditor.getTextField().requestFocusInWindow();`  Form the docs. *"Requests that this Component get the input focus, **if this Component's top-level ancestor is already the focused Window."***  If the frame is not yet visible, it will definitely **not** be the focused window.

Comment: @Andrew, That line can be deleted from the code and the program still works the same: as the first, and only, object on the frame it does get the focus correctly but does not *show* that it has the focus.  When this happens in a big program, the user doesn't know where the focus is.

Comment: Perhaps I should have prefaced that with *"OT: BTW.."* ;)  Yes, I was aware of the rest of your comment.  But it was perhaps useful as further info. for anyone else.  :)  Sorry I don't run OS X so cannot really test it here.  BTW - what is the 'default' PLAF for OS X?  Is it the Aqua (native) PLAF or Metal?

Comment: BTW - I'm guessing this still happens if you comment out `spinnerEditor.getTextField().setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); spinnerEditor.getTextField().setForeground(Color.GREEN);`?  What about `setEditable(false);` (as suggested in a now deleted answer)?

Comment: @Andrew - I'm using the Aqua (native) PLAF, which I believe is the default for OS X.  With CENTER and GREEN commented out the situation still happens - spinner has the focus, but is not *shown* to have the focus. With setEditable commented out or setEditable(true), the focus IS *shown*, but I only want the arrow keys on the spinner or keyboard to work so that's why I have it set false.